# TextView multiple line printing

Tags: swift

I write UITextView multi-line text, move to the bottom line with the enter key or press the skip key on the keyboard and write a few lines of text. It prints the text as optional ("text") because I don't sync the text to the string value. When I print it as string value, it doesn't see the bottom line. What is the solution to this?

```
let jsString = "createText('\(textInputArea.text)')"

@IBOutlet weak var textInputArea: UITextView!
```

My current output is:
Optional ( "line1
line2
line3 ")

If I synchronize to string, I get the "line1" output only

Comment: Add the current and expected output.

Comment: I updated topics